# Palantir Foundry - Is it possible to retrieve the user that last updated an uploaded table?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to create a historical dataset from a snapshot uploaded table in Palantir Foundry. I want to add into that table the user who did the upload. Is that possible?

Can't find on the docs info about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransformInput object doesn't contain that information.

You could use an API call to the Foundry build service to get the information about the latest update performed on the input dataset but that might give you wrong information if there were multiple updates from different people since you last ran the transform. This also requires Palantir to allow calling Foundry APIs from your repository if it's not already enabled.